# Delete set number of characters following the first character

Tags: excel

I have dummy emails that are too long. I want to shorten them but I don't want to delete the first parenthesis.

"est@scelerisque.ca"
"fermentum@fringillacursus.edu"
"adipiscing@arcuVivamussit.com"
"vitae.aliquet@Sed.edu"
"magna.tellus@Nullamnisl.com"
"placerat.eget@purusNullam.org"

Is it possible for me to delete for example the first 3 letters after the (") and the next 3 letters after @ and stop at the dot?

As i ask this, it sounds really complicated. I may just use the same email for all users since it's just dummy data :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one email in each cell, you can create an excel formula which will
convert email values for you.

Delete 3 letters after ":

> =CHAR(34) & MID(A1, 5, LEN(A1))

(Using result of previous formula in B1):
Skip 3 letters after @:

> =MID(B1, 1, FIND("@", B1)) & (MID(B1, FIND("@", B1)+4, LEN(B1)))

(Using result of previous formula in C1):
Stop at the dot (also keep " at the end):

> =MID(C1, 1, FIND(".",C1)-1 ) & CHAR(34)